# Magento2: Add a new page layout

Tags: magento2, module, layout

On the page layouts 1 column, 2 columns, 3 columns, there is always a div called "columns" in it. I would like to create a page layout, where that div does not exist. How can I do that? Where is that file / where do I need to copy it to my theme?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create two files for custom layout

**1 - Create layouts.xml**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml

This file will registered custom layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="custom">
        <label translate="true">custom layout</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

After creating above file you can check your custom layout in admin panel.

**2 - Create custom.xml**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/page_layout/custom.xml

This file will manage design for your layout page.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Now, flush the cache and check the new custom layout in admin panel configuration setting.

**Check this link for the full article: [blog.mageprince.com](https://blog.mageprince.com/how-to-add-a-new-page-layout-in-magento-2/)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot. Where would I need to copy these files in my own theme folder? And How can I prevent that the div "column main" is in the layout? thanks!

Comment: @N1njaWTF see my updated answer.

Comment: I tried it, but it gives me a white page with this custom layout (Magento 2.2.0), I get the following error message in the logs: main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.panel.wrapper' element cannot be added as child to 'header.container', because the latter doesn't exist [] []

Comment: @PrincePatel, how can add CSS and JS file for particular this **custom layout** layout? Is it possible?

Comment: its working but, the customer info like email and id not fetched when this layout is set for any page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change inside layout XML file in your custom theme.

Copy the

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

If you want to display product details page **2column left** then change file is **catalog_product_view.xml**, set layout value **layout="2columns-right"** inside `<page>` node.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

---

If you want it for cms pages, you can do it using the admin panel, just go to **Content > Pages > Select the page**, from the left bar, select the **Design** tab, on the **Layout drop-down** on the right select the 2 columns right.

[image: CMS Page Design]